# Java Jersey Framework RESTful Webservices Best Practices

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I am working on a project to provide RESTful API for a hospital related data transaction stuff. And I am using Jersey to be the server side framework for me.

However, apart from the accepted notion of dividing the code into resources, models and data access, I can't find information that provides some helpful best practices on the subject.

Any useful suggestions?

Comment: Aside from the things you mentioned, I like setting up JPA (persistence api) to manage my resources, using JAXB to marshal/unmarshal json+xml objects, and using a properties file for any additional data i need.

Comment: I am looking for info that tells me where to manage exceptions, or data connections etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to compile some best practices that I learnt into some topics.

### JPA and ORM

If you use an ORM, then use JPA. It helps to keep your ORM of choice and the application loosely coupled, i.e. you can easily switch between ORM's.

### Dependency Injection

This is an awesome way, again, to keep your application as much as loosely coupled as possible. Use Guice or Spring. Basically, with this you can inject generic instances on your classes without coupling them with their concrete implementation.
Useful with DAO's. You can inject a `GenericDao` (interface) in your JAX-RS classes, but the true implementation of it is a JpaDao, for instance.
Also, this is awesome to quickly switch to test environments. When testing some logic in your application, you probably don't want to use the database but just a dummy implementation of your GenericDao, for example. I consider using DAO's itself as another important best practice.

### Security

I have some questions about this on my profile, but basically use OAuth or HTTP Basic/Digest + SSL (HTTPS). It's a bit hard to accomplish security the way you want, surprisingly. You can use the security mechanisms your Servlet Container may provide or something internal to your application like Apache Shiro, Spring Security or even manually defining your security filters.

### HATEOAS (and other REST contraints)

Most RESTful API's aren't REST. People often misunderstand this: REST implies a set of contraints. When these constraints aren't met, it's simply an HTTP API, which is also ok. In any case, I advise you to link your resource representations so that the client can navigate through your API. This is called HATEOAS and I merely scratched the surface on this matter. Please read more about REST if you want a true REST API with all its benefits.

### Maven

This is a special best practice, not related to the application itself, but to its development. Indeed, Maven increases productivity a lot, specially due to its dependency management capabilities. I couldn't live without it.

I don't know if this information was useful to you. I hope it was.
If you need information about any other topic, I'll edit the answer if I know it.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the above answers, designing the resources keeping the HTTP verbs out of your base URLs, carefully selecting the @PathParam, @QueryParam, @FormParam and @FormDataParam annotations are something I strongly emphasize.

For error handling, I return a Response object with HTTP response codes to convey the error to the client calling my API.

```
return Response.status(<HTTPErrorCode>).entity("Error msg here or my Error Bean object as an argument").build();
```

Using documentation tools like Swagger API helps a lot in developer testing.

Brian Mulloy's Web API design [eBook](http://go.apigee.com/trk?t=2&mid=MzUxLVdYWS0xNjY6MDoxMTA2OjIzNDowOjExNTU6Nzo4ODAyNi0xOm51bGw=&&&http://pages.apigee.com/rs/apigee/images/api-design-ebook-2012-03.pdf?mkt_tok=3RkMMJWWfF9wsRonuqzPZKXonjHpfsXw4%2bwvX7Hr08Yy0EZ5VunJEUWy2YIESdQ/cOedCQkZHblFnV8NS62iRLkNq6ML) and Vinay Sahni's [post](http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api) had been a handy resource for me to review/correct my design.